# misspelled "chcecked" in the notification mail

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, spelling, email-notification

I just received an email from Stack Exchange `<do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>`, which has a misspelled word "chcecked". It should be "checked".

> The following items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last chcecked it on

Screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't chceck your email all the time? :P

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be "czeched"?

Comment: Wow, Shadow Wizard's willing to give away 500 reputation for an 'answer' to this?

Comment: @Coulton not answer, fix. This bug really annoys me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've had this fixed for a while, but apparently never built the project out to production.

Derp derp.

Comment: Thanks, hope it means it's now built into production? :)

Comment: Yes, it is fixed now: "since you last _checked_ it on 2014-10-28". Looks like bounty actually worked. :-)

Comment: Easiest 500 rep I've ever made. ;)